# boot menu disappeared in Ubuntu after the security updates?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I am using Ubuntu 9.10 for last 2 months along with Vista. It was working fine until the yesterday ubuntu security update. After the installation & reboot, i couldnt boot the ubuntu.

In Boot loader screen, it shows both Vista & ubuntu options. But on selecting the ubuntu boot option, it took me to the GRUB command terminal, instead the Ubuntu boot menu.

And i found the menu.lst file is missing in the boot\grub\ directory. I am sure i havent deleted the file.

can someone guide me, how to resolve this

Cheers

RameshVel

Comment: Weird that it shows the items, but there's no menu.lst.

Answer (score 1):

`update-grub` will regenerate your menu.lst file when logged in Ubuntu.

Here's [how to boot into Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GrubHowto#Manually%20boot%20into%20a%20Linux%20OS) in the first place.

Comment: you could also boot using a liveCD, in case you arent sure what your partition info is